# Can I fool Windows into thinking a virus scanner is installed?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, anti-virus

I'm trying to allow programmatic access to Outlook without getting an annoying popup.  This is configurable under Tools -> Trust Center, however my outlook warns

```
Antivirus Status: Invalid.
```

Which is true because I don't have any antivirus software, nor do I want any thank you very much Microsoft.  My question is is there some sort of really lightweight fake virus scanner which will satisfy the condition of appearing to Windows as a virus scanner without actually doing anything?

I am aware this falls firmly in the camp of "Dangerous, but I know what I'm doing"

Comment: has been asked before: http://superuser.com/questions/16273/which-is-the-best-light-weight-antivirus and closed in favor of http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows (maybe you should change your title to something like "is there something like a fake virusscanner to fool windows"

Answer (score 4):

ClamAV is very lightweight and very free, though I'm not sure it will satisfy MS's security center requirements. Give it a try though, I have yet to see an AV lighter than Clam, and the price is certainly right.

edit: link - http://www.clamav.net/

Answer (score 0):

Does Outlook do its own check for an antivirus program or does it check with Windows?  If it checks with Windows, maybe you can suppress the message by telling Windows not to track antivirus stats?  Try unchecking "Virus Protection" under Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>Action Center>Change Action Center settings .

Comment: That having been said, ClamAV or MSE (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials) aren't going to slow down any computer made in the last decade except when running full scans, and they're both free.  You owe it to yourself to use an antivirus - your computer will be more secure for zero work.