# Fake anti-virus?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I fool Windows into thinking a virus scanner is installed?](https://superuser.com/questions/25703/can-i-fool-windows-into-thinking-a-virus-scanner-is-installed)

For "authentication" purposes I'm required to have an up-to-date anti-virus and firewall installed on my computer. I suspect the check is done with Windows (7), as it is capable of monitoring anti-virus and firewall status.

Of course anti-viruses are simply a waste of computer resources so I don't want to install a real one. My question is if there are any good (non-malicious, effective) "fake" anti-viruses that simply pretend an AV is on your computer to trick Windows, without actually having the functionality behind them.

Comment: What do you mean by "authentication" purposes?

Comment: Who are you trying to fool?  Just install the anti-virus required by IT department.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/25703/fake-virus-scanner?rq=1

Comment: actually I call for duplicate

Comment: Yes my IT department requires it. I'm sure it's necessary for secretaries and such and it's fine on their own hardware, but when running a VM at home and it's sluggish enough without AV.

Answer (score 12):

Don't be silly.  Run the AV required by your IT department.  As someone who works in a corporate IT department, I know your type.  You are smarter than them, know more about computers, and could teach them everything they need to know.  Or you could do your job, and not circumvent them doing their jobs.

> Of course anti-viruses are simply a waste of computer resources so I don't want to install a real one. My question is if there are any good (non-malicious, effective) "fake" anti-viruses that simply pretend an AV is on your computer to trick Windows, without actually having the functionality behind them.

Seriously, just run the AV, don't be **that** person.

Comment: The point is I'm using my own computer and will secure it however I want. I've never used an AV and never had a problem. On the other hand I've seen botnets of thousands of computers with every assortment of AV installed. You tell me how effective they are.

Comment: Yes, it is your own personal computer.  Maybe its time to request a laptop from your IT department.  Make sure you tell them that you are explicitly trying to circumvent security measures and request that are in place by people who for lack of a better term, know quite a bit more about security then you do.

Comment: User76211, I agree with your answer. As a side note, you should make an actual account on SU. I believe you can merge your user account to the new one too.